# What is a common idiom for closing AsynchronousFileChannel?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I just found that following code doesn't work as expected.

```java
try (AsynchronousFileChannel channel = open(path)) {
    channel.read(, , ,
                 new CompletionHandler() {
                         @Override
                         public void completed(Integer result, Long attachment) {
                         }
                         @Override
                         public void failed(Throwable exc, Long attachment) {
                             // channel already has been closed!!!
                         }
                 });
}
```

Because the `AsynchronousFileChannel#read` method returns instantly and the `CompletionHandler` just can't work.

What is the common idiom for closing the channel, after tasks are done?

Should I just do this?

```java
AsynchronousFileChannel channel = open(path);

channel.read(, , ,
             new CompletionHandler() {
                     @Override
                     public void completed(Integer result, Long attachment) {
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void failed(Throwable exc, Long attachment) {
                     }
             });

channel.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully someone knows a proper way to ensure that all in-progress `AsynchronousFileChannel` callbacks are finished - I could not find a suitable API call to end a read operation with callbacks. In tests, I noticed that the `CompletionHandler` callbacks may be called after my method call returned data read to its caller, well after leaving the try with resources block below which closes the `AsynchronousFileChannel`:

```
try (AsynchronousFileChannel fc = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(p, StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
    var handler = new CompletionHandler<Integer,Long>() {
        public void completed(Integer result, Long position) {
            // ...
        }
        public void failed(Throwable exc, Long position) {
            // ...
        }
    };
    // Run some reads:
    fc.read(aByteBuffer, startPos, Long.valueOf(startPos), handler);
}
return blah; 
// "handler" still can receive callbacks after this point!
```

Instead I used a workaround using a `CountDownLatch` inside the method so that the try-catch block did not exit until all the `fc.read` calls were matched with a corresponding callback to `CompletionHandler completed / failed`.

```
try (AsynchronousFileChannel fc = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(p, StandardOpenOption.READ)) {

    // Work out how many fc.read calls you plan to do
    int numberOfReads = 1;
    CountDownLatch countdown = new CountDownLatch(numberOfReads);

    var handler = new CompletionHandler<Integer,Long>() {
        public void completed(Integer result, Long position) {
            // ...
            countdown.countDown();
        }
        public void failed(Throwable exc, Long position) {
            // ...
            countdown.countDown();
        }
    };

    // Kick off numberOfReads x fc.read
    fc.read(yourByteBuffer, startPos, Long.valueOf(startPos), handler);

    // Without next line the AsynchronousFileChannel may continue to run after return
    countdown.await();
}
return blah; 
// No more "handler" callbacks after this point
```

It is not an ideal solution, as it relies on calculating the number of reads before creating the `CountDownLatch`. Instead you might consider a dynamic counter or use the non-callback read method: `Future<Integer> fut = read(ByteBuffer, long)` style and call `fut.get();` in the caller thread instead.